# Why should I use notify?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm reading through my SCJP book and I'm on the chapter about threads, and I am wondering why you should use notify at all.

Here is my sample program using notify:

```
class ThreadA {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ThreadB b = new ThreadB();
        b.start();

        synchronized(b){
            try{
                System.out.println("Waiting for b to complete...");
                b.wait();
            }catch(InterruptedException e) {}
            System.out.println("Total is: " + b.total);
        }
    }
}

class ThreadB extends Thread {
    int total;
    public void run() {
        synchronized(this) {
            for(int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++){
                total++;
            }
            notify();
        }       
        for(int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++){
            total++;
        }
    }
}
```

If I take out the notify call, it still executes in the same way. I.E., once the lock is released, the b.wait() stops blocking eventually and we get a semi random number between 100000000 and 200000000, depending on the scheduler.

This code:

```
class ThreadA {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ThreadB b = new ThreadB();
        b.start();

        synchronized(b){
            try{
                System.out.println("Waiting for b to complete...");
                b.wait();
            }catch(InterruptedException e) {}
            System.out.println("Total is: " + b.total);
        }
    }
}

class ThreadB extends Thread {
    int total;
    public void run() {
        synchronized(this) {
            for(int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++){
                total++;
            }
            notify();
        }       
    }
}
```

Always results in 100000000 getting printed regardless wither the notify is there or not.

And this code:

```
class ThreadA {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ThreadB b = new ThreadB();
        b.start();

        synchronized(b){
            try{
                System.out.println("Waiting for b to complete...");
                b.wait();
            }catch(InterruptedException e) {}
            System.out.println("Total is: " + b.total);
        }
    }
}

class ThreadB extends Thread {
    int total;
    public void run() {
        synchronized(this) {
            for(int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++){
                total++;
            }
            notify();
            for(int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++){
                total++;
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Always prints out 200000000 regardless of the notify being present or absent.

So as far as I can tell, the only thing the notify does is possibly waking up a thread earlier than needed, if that is the case, why use notify at all? Why not wait for the lock to be released and let the JVM restart the other thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you or someone else calls `notify()`, the `wait()` *should* continue forever, barring spurious wakes. Are you sure nothing's interrupting the thread?

Basically you use `notify()` precisely to wake up threads. If you don't need to put a thread to sleep until another thread can notify it that it should wake up, don't use it.

EDIT: Okay, I've reproduced this behaviour - and I suspect it's because you're calling `wait()` on the thread object itself. My guess is that the `Thread` object gets notified when the thread terminates.

Try waiting on a shared plain `Object`, like this:

```
class ThreadA {

    static Object monitor = new Object();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadB b = new ThreadB();
        b.start();

        synchronized(monitor) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Waiting for b to complete...");
                monitor.wait();
            }catch(InterruptedException e) {}
            System.out.println("Total is: " + b.total);
        }
    }
}

class ThreadB extends Thread {
    int total;
    public void run() {

        synchronized(ThreadA.monitor) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
                total++;
            }
//            ThreadA.monitor.notify();
        }       
    }
}
```

If you uncomment that line, the program terminates - otherwise it doesn't.

EDIT: I've actually found some documentation on this. From [`Thread.join(millis, nanos)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28long,%20int%29):

> As a thread terminates the this.notifyAll method is invoked. It is recommended that applications not use wait, notify, or notifyAll on Thread instances.

Comment: So you're saying that ThreadA waking up after the lock it's waiting on has expired or the thread owning that lock exited is not guaranteed behavior?

Comment: @Malfist: Absolutely. I believe it's only because you *happened* to be waiting on the `Thread` object itself.

Comment: @Malfist: My guess is that some part of the `Thread` code calls `notify()` when the thread exits. Just another reason not to lock or wait on arbitrary objects - only do it on an object that you control completely.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything that looks like it would cause that behavior here: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Thread.java.html

Comment: @Malfist: Sure, it may well be undocumented - it may even be JVM-specific. Doesn't that just encourage you even more *not to `wait()` on a Thread object*?

Comment: Yes it does, but it still makes me curious as to why thread behaves this way.

Comment: @Malfist: Have found some documentation confirming the notification *and* reaffirming my recommendation not to call wait (etc) on Thread objects. See the bottom of my edited answer.

Comment: @Jon, yes java threads sync. on themselves and do call `notify()` on exit. Half an year ago I posted why synchronization on `Thread` should be avoided. It heavily synchronizes on itself (partly to even follow the spec).